# ChangePasswordFailure .. ChangePassword control

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, change-password

Every time i try to change a password to any other password. It invalidates my passwords (the new password, and confirmed password).. and then the ChangePasswordFailureText appears.

I dealt with that problem before in the config file, i simply changed

```
  <add    
      name="MyMembershipProvider"     
      type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"   
      connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer"  
      minRequiredPasswordLength="2"     
      minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" />// This to 0 and it solved the problem
  </providers>
```

But with that control, i dont know what to change, to make it accept the new password

```
<asp:ChangePassword ID="ChangePassword1" runat="server" 
    ChangePasswordButtonText="שנה סיסמה" ChangePasswordFailureText="סיסמה לא תקינה" 
    ChangePasswordTitleText="איפוס סיסמה" 
    ConfirmNewPasswordLabelText="הקלד את הסיסמה החדשה שוב:" 
    ConfirmPasswordCompareErrorMessage="הסיסמה החדשה והאימות שלה לא תואמים" 
    ConfirmPasswordRequiredErrorMessage="דרוש אימות של הסיסמה החדשה" 
    NewPasswordLabelText="סיסמה חדשה:" 
    NewPasswordRegularExpressionErrorMessage="בבקשה הכנס סיסמה שונה" 
    NewPasswordRequiredErrorMessage="דרושה סיסמה חדשה" PasswordLabelText="סיסמה:" 
    PasswordRequiredErrorMessage="יש צורך בסיסמה" SuccessText="סיסמתך שונתה" 
    SuccessTitleText="שינוי הסיסמה בוצע" UserNameLabelText="שם משתמש:" 
    UserNameRequiredErrorMessage="יש צורך בשם משתמש" CancelButtonText="בטל" 
    CancelDestinationPageUrl="~/Registration.aspx">
    <ValidatorTextStyle BorderColor="Red" />
</asp:ChangePassword>
```

*Some text in Hebrew, but it shouldnt be an issue

Comment: Can you post your control markup?

Comment: i should have edited it from the begining

Comment: NewPasswordRegularExpression does not seem to be there.  I guess the question is which error message is it giving...  not the text just which one it is please.

Comment: I think it wants a special symbol in the question..(pleumorti..or something..). As noted before , ChangePasswordFailureText.. that property is being triggered. It is triggered when the password doesnt have numbers and special symbols inside!!!

Comment: So did the password have a number or special char in it?  I am wondering if it has something to do with the hebrew text.  Do you define the UI Culture in your application?